# Looking for answers related to custom images and installers

Tags: repository, debian-installer, livecd, preseed

Okay so I'm attempting to build my own custom live CD and eventually a distro based on Debian, using the `live-build` tools and squashfs-tools/chroot to modify the image. I'm also playing around with 
LinuxFromScratch, but my questions right now are mainly about the `debian-installer` and possibly `preseeding`, What I'd like to know is how i can force `debian-installer` to use a custom package repo, for example, how would Kali-Linux seed "Kali-rolling" or Ubuntu with their own repos. 
I've mirrored the Debian 8 repo (udebs and source included), and created my own repo using `aptly` I then imported all packages from the mirror into my own repo, along with some others I'd tested beforehand.
Now the problem is possibly the naming for the distribution and the components, as I chose to set up the repo with a distribution/suite name other than **jessie**, and components have been merged into one component which I called "**universe**" like what is is used by Ubuntu.

I know where preseed files should be put, and I've successfully modified the installer with a `preseed.cfg` file to skip creation of a new user other than root (I know most would advise against this but it's personal preference to create users after install), but when I try add a custom mirror in the preseed file, the installer seems to just ignore it and asks me if I'd like to use an arbitrary Debian mirror.

So how can I make changes to the installer or preseed file so that it can use this custom distro/suite and component during install?

This is what I tried:

> ```
> d-i passwd/make-user boolean false
> d-i netcfg/hostname string redebian
> d-i netcfg/get_nameservers string 8.8.8.8
> d-i mirror/protocol string http
> d-i mirror/http/hostname string xx.xx.xx.xx
> d-i mirror/http/directory string /
> d-i mirror/http/proxy string
> d-i mirror/suite string redebian
> d-i mirror/udeb/suite string redebian
> d-i apt-setup/universe boolean true
> ```

There's no problems adding the repo directly to `/etc/apt/sources.list` 
I just don't know how to add it to the installer etc; even when I try select it manually, it tells me it's a bad mirror because it's only looking for the URL and directory; it doesn't ask about which suite and components to use.

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, eventually I looked into `/var/log/syslog` and saw some odd things, such as the installer making requests to the specified mirror with the "wrong" suite/codename, I wondered where it was pulling that value from, so I extracted the ISO with `bsdtar` as I'd done before in order to place the `preseed.cfg` file.
I noticed this time there was a hidden directory named `.disk` inside there were some configuration files that the installer apparently must use to get some values during install. I changed these values to the desired values, then changed the name of the of the `dists/jessie` directory to `dists/redebian`, recreated the symlinks for `stable`, `unstable`, and `testing` so they point to `redebian`, altered the `Release` files on the **ISO** so they contained information the same as my repository, then finally recalculated all the md5sums.

Now `debian-installer` is recognizing the published **repo** as being a valid mirror.

I did still have a problem installing `grub` afterwards, but I'm sure I'll work that one out eventually.